# how to place a subview on a cell so it does not block the tapgesture of its superview(cell)

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have the following code on a custom cell -

```
   PSCollectionViewTapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[PSCollectionViewTapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSelectView:)];
                gr.delegate = self;
                [newView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
                newView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

how can i pass this gesture to its subviews? instead of adding a new gesture on subview.
currently the subview is blocking half of the view but tapping on it doesn't do anything.

Comment: As a hint, tap gestures don't take any space on your view.  They respond to taps ON the view, but they aren't a part of the view hierarchy themselves.  I. E. they aren't visible, so can't block 'half' the view.  Something else is there.

Comment: what i meant was i have added a subview on the top of my view so when i tap on the subview it does not work but when i tap on the rest it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

needed to disable subviews interaction